# Flask: How to delete files from the server

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to delete two files from my flask application. But it does not work

html

```html
<button href="/remove/wellness" id="remove" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Remove</button>
```

Here is my delete function:

```
@app.route('/remove/<file_id>')
def remove(file_id):
    filename_jsonl = f"{file_id}.jsonl"
    filename_csv = f"{file_id}.csv"

    return os.remove(filename_jsonl, filename_csv)
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do ```filename_json1``` and ```filename_csv``` contain the correct values?

Comment: `TypeError: remove() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)`

Comment: Thank. Now a new mistake `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── templates
│   └── delete_files.html
├── wellness.csv
└── wellness.jsonl
```

As you can see I have two files called `wellness.csv` and `wellness.jsonl` in the directory where I have placed my `app.py` file. The name `wellness` will be passed from the template and these two files will be deleted from the directory.

`app.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def search():
    return render_template('delete_files.html')

@app.route('/remove/<file_id>')
def remove(file_id):
    filename_jsonl = f"{file_id}.jsonl"
    filename_csv = f"{file_id}.csv"
    try:
        os.remove(filename_jsonl)
        os.remove(filename_csv)
        return "Files are deleted successfully"
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error in deleting files: {e}"
```

`delete_files.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Delete files using button click in Flask</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/remove/wellness" id="remove" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Remove</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

After clicking the delete button I see the message `Files are deleted successfully`.

[image: after successfully deletion of the files]

The folder structure after deletion of the files:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── delete_files.html
```

**Update**

If you want to redirect to root url after successful deletion you can use `redirect` method like below:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def search():
    return render_template('delete_files.html')

@app.route('/remove/<file_id>')
def remove(file_id):
    filename_jsonl = f"{file_id}.jsonl"
    filename_csv = f"{file_id}.csv"
    try:
        os.remove(filename_jsonl)
        os.remove(filename_csv)
        return redirect(url_for('search'))
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error in deleting files: {e}"
```

Comment: Thanks! What can I do to prevent messages from being displayed?

Comment: Can I use return redirect ('/')?